# How to transfer Whatsapp to new phone

Tags: sync, whatsapp-messenger, titanium-backup

I had been using Whatsapp on my old phone. I would like to transfer the messages to the new one. I had disabled uploading to google drive as I consider this too insecure. On the new phone I installed whatsapp but no messages were there.

I remember being able to do this in the past as Whatsapp integration with google drive is a relatively new feature, how did it used to work, did it download the saved messages from the whatsapp server? Since they're still on my old phone I hope they're retrievable. I'm considering using Titanium Backup to make a copy. Would this work?

When I try to open whatsapp on my old phone, it said the number cannot be verified (because I took the SIM card out and put it in my new phone) but I can still see in the background all the old messages.

Comment: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20887921#restore

Comment: you can try this: (1)Backup old phone WhatsApp using Titanium backup. Copy the WhatsApp folder of old phone. (2) Restore WhatsApp into new phone using Titanium (Do not open it now), Place WhatsApp folder(oldphone's) to internal storage of new phone. (3) Open WhatsApp, it will start from beginning setup process, and restores upto today's 2AM backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two ways you can restore your whatsapp messages from old phone to your new phone.

**1) Using Titanium Backup**

- Backup Whatsapp app+data in old phone.
- Copy the titanium backup of whatsapp to the new phone.
- Restore data in new phone.

**2) Copying Manually the messages**

- Copy the contents of SDCard/whatsapp/Databases from old phone to new phone
- Paste the files in exactly the same location.
- Verify using your number

Comment: Should highlight, it only works to restore data to new phone, not app + data.

Comment: Actually you can restore app+data also. I don't see how app version is relevant here ?

Comment: When I tried app+data it didn't work, but when I tried just data it did. Though I had already installed and tried using Whatsapp before so maybe that messed it up.